# No hanging indent with biblatex in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I try to get rid of the hanging indent in my bibliography. The `biblatex` manual suggests `\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}`, but it does not work in this case.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-angew,
    articletitle=true,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {2},
  title = {Nanoscale magnetic skyrmions in metallic films and multilayers: a new twist for spintronics Nanoscale magnetic skyrmions in metallic films and multilayers: a new twist for spintronics},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{D04}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How do I avoid the indentation for the second (and third) line of the reference?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bibliography` environment for `numeric` and `alphabetic` styles does not use `\bibhang`, because they work more like an `enumerate`. In those lists, all lines have the same indentation, but additionally there is a label on the first line.

So you if you want to use `\bibhang` you need something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-angew,
    articletitle=true,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item
   \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
   \addspace}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{sigfridsson,cicero,worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

A simpler solution is

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\trivlist}
  {\endtrivlist}
  {\item
   \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}%
   \addspace}
```

Comment: Yes. Could you tell me, why 'bibhang' does not work?

Comment: @Andy The definition of `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` does not include `\bibhang` for the `numeric` styles. That is because the numeric styles work more like an `enumerate` list, where the indentation is automatically determined by the label number. We had to change the entire bibliography environment to get things to work here.

Answer (score 3):

A solution consists in redefining the `bibenvironment`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-angew,
    articletitle=true,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {2},
  title = {Nanoscale magnetic skyrmions in metallic films and multilayers: a new twist for spintronics Nanoscale magnetic skyrmions in metallic films and multilayers: a new twist for spintronics},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
 {\list
 {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
 {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%{\labelwidth}%
 \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
 %\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
 \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
 \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
 \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss\hspace{\dimexpr\labelnumberwidth+\labelsep}##1}}
 {\endlist}
 {\item}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{D04}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]